# What does :~ evaluate to in Bash?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

What does :~ evaluate to in Bash? I've accidentally ran the command `mv somefile.txt :~` while logged in as a root user. The PEM key I use to login as that user no longer works and when I attempt to login, I'm prompted for a password that I do not know.

I have another user that I can login with, but that user does not have root privileges. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (it's an old test server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this on my machine, which created a file named `:~`

```
mv somefile.txt :~
```

Can you check if there is a file created named `:~`? You can move the file back using:

```
mv \:~ somefile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry it turned out that the home directory was actually moved some different, which is why I can't login. I did find the :~ file :)